# How do I search a directory of files using another file as input and sending the output to another file?

Tags: unix, search, file, awk, grep

I am working on a Unix system.  I have a directory of files called MailHistory.  Each file in the directory contains all of the emails for the previous day.
The files are created at midnight and named with the timedatestamp.  So, a typical filename is 20090323000100.

I have a file that has a list of names.  Using this file as input, I need to search the MailHistory directory.   The results of the search
need only return the filename of the file that contains the name being searched.

This is an example of the names in the file:
GADDIS, SHUREE V.
HERWEYER, JILL RENEE
KAPENGA, TRICIA JAMI
MOTON, VIOLA
NELSON, TAMMY K
OBERLIN, DAVID LYNN
PALS, WILLIAM BRYANT
PEARSON-BUNCH, ELESE

The emails will have names in the same format (LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME) and case (UPPER).  I want to send the output to a file.

Thanks in Advance,
Corey

Answer (score 1):

grep -rlFf names_file MailHistory > matches

Answer (score 0):

cat list | xargs -I{} grep -l "SHUREE V\. HERWEYER" {} > matches

Remember you'll need to escape () dots in the search string

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l SEARCH_TERM -r MailHistory
```

or, if you don't want to recursively check the directory:

```
cd MailHistory; grep -l SEARCH_TERM *; cd -
```